# How to intercept event of dev reload on React Native?

Tags: react-native

How can I intercept the reloading process on Android (Dev menu -> Reload)? 
I want to clear some part of Redux store when is happend the action.

Comment: Please elaborate what you are asking here little more. I am not able to get your question.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question. It is really not clear what you intend with that large screen shot in the first place. It doesnt add any meaningful information to your question!

Answer (score 0):

The question provides quite a little insight but seeing that some working is required on the redux store every time there is a reload, you can catch [INIT action](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L258) fired by Redux every time the store is initialised, IMO